# Why basic_stringbuf and basic_filebuf move constructors have implementation defined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

From my copy of the C++ standard [§27.8.2.1p4]:

> basic_stringbuf(basic_stringbuf&& rhs);
>
> Effects: Move constructs from the rvalue rhs. **It is
>   implementation-defined whether the sequence pointers in *this
>   (eback(), gptr(), egptr(), pbase(), pptr(), epptr()) obtain the values
>   which rhs had**. Whether they do or not, *this and rhs reference
>   separate buffers (if any at all) after the construction. The openmode,
>   locale and any other state of rhs is also copied.

A similar sentence is also used for `basic_filebuf(basic_filebuf&& rhs);`.

**Question**

I was wondering why this is implementation defined? Is there a reason why you might not want to copy over the pointers?

Comment: About fifty really smart people got together to talk about it and nobody agreed.

Comment: My impression is that they don't want to define resource management. Leave it to the implementors. Which is understandable.

Comment: I hate to be an ass about it but... chapter and verse please

Comment: @HansPassant: Fifty smart people disagreed enough to form a camel, about which nine million smarter people took the mickey afterwards.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't think that the lack of chapter and paragraph really matters... The fact that it is the requirement on the move constructor of `basic_stringbuf` is detailed enough. In case you don't want to search the document, it is §27.8.2.1p4

Comment: Could someone please enlighten me why one would want same pointer values with different buffers. Don't these pointers point into buffer. OH, ok, past tense, *had*, yes. Nead moar coffea.

Comment: "implementation-defined" behavior is often specified by committees when existing implementations already differed, and there was no good reason to force them all to conform to a specific behavior.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thank you for providing the chapter and verse as requested. Yes, it matters. Providing citations is and has always been one of the fundamental bases of scientific documentation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A different way of quoting the chapter is by the annotation on the right **[stringbuf.cons]**, where the constructors for `stringbuf` are defined. I agree that in science you need to provide precise quotes, but in this case the document is known (the standard), and the organization of the document is clear enough that it takes just a few seconds to locate the quote.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Still, it's polite to provide the reference when asking for help rather than forcing your volunteers to search for it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious implementation techniques to cope with the buffer in the standard stream buffers:

1. You can embed the buffer into the object, creating a bigger footprint for the object but avoiding a memory allocation for small strings or files.
2. You can point to a buffer allocated on the heap and dealing with a potentially large buffer at the cost of a memory allocation.

Depending on the implementation choice of where the buffer lives you'll want a new set of pointer values or you'll want to carry over the pointers as is is. Neither strategy is "better" and I can imagine variations combining the strategies as well. So, instead of making a choice implementations can choose. If your question is why the implementation is supposed to [forget to] document the choice it made: That is distinctly beyond me. My personal guess is that it was assumed that the phase "is implementation defined" would provide the freedom of choice and it was ignored that the implications is that the implementation needs to state its choice (since there was a debate about quotes: 1.3.10 [defns.impl.defined] - oddly without a paragraph number).

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. If the buffer is not allocated on the heap then the only thing you can do is copy, and in that situation you would want a new set of pointer values. Correct?